# Why do I have to delete the calls to "super.doGet(req, resp)" and "super.doPost(req, resp)"?

Tags: java, jsp, exception, servlets

I was trying to pass values from a servlet to my jsp page using the code below:

```
package lecture_mvc.mvc.simple;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class SimpleController extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.doGet(req, resp);
        processRequest(req,resp);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.doPost(req, resp);
        processRequest(req,resp);
    }
    
    private void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String type = request.getParameter("type");
        Object resultObject = null;
        if (type == null || type.equals("greeting")) {
            resultObject = "Hello";
        } else if (type.equals("date")) {
            resultObject = new java.util.Date();
        } else {
            resultObject = "Invalid Type";
        }
        
        request.setAttribute("result", resultObject);
        
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/simpleView.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

but it throws a `java.lang.IllegalStateException`.

So I deleted the `super.doGet(req, resp);` and `super.doPost(req, resp);` code and then it works well.

What is the problem with using those lines of code?

Comment: So did you read the message that is in the IllegalStateException? Because it probably tells you exactly why.

Answer (score 0):

To create a servlet to handle requests, you need to extend `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet` and override any methods you need (as in your example, it's usually just `doGet` and `doPost`. You are overriding the methods but you also invoke the default implementation of `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet`.

`javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet` doesn't know what you want to do so its implementation just returns an error back to the client. The code is [something like this](https://github.com/javaee/servlet-spec/blob/master/src/main/java/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.java):

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws ServletException, IOException
{
    String protocol = req.getProtocol();
    String msg = lStrings.getString("http.method_get_not_supported");
    if (protocol.endsWith("1.1")) {
        resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED, msg);
    } else {
        resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, msg);
    }
}
```

The response is generated with `resp.sendError`. If you read the [JavaDoc for this method](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError-int-), it says (emphasis mine):

> If the response has already been committed, this method throws an IllegalStateException. **After using this method, the response should be considered to be committed and should not be written to**.

When you then go back into your code, you do a `dispatcher.forward(request, response);`, but the response has already been committed by the `super.doGet` or `super.doPost` call. You can't write to a committed response any longer because the response content has already been written to the output stream and sent to the client. When you do that, you get what you described in you post, an illegal state exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed

So, in short:

- When you call `super.doGet` or `super.doPost` and then your code, you basically try to write the response twice, so you get the illegal state exception.
- Removing the calls to `super.doGet` or `super.doPost` just allows your code to handle the request and generate a single response, and that's why it works.